# A http 204 response returns a blank page in iOS, is there a way to stop this?

Tags: ios, node.js, http, express, http-status-codes

This may have been asked before but I can't seem to find a solution, so apologies if this is the case.

I have a simple node app in development which uses express. One of the post routes returns a http 204 and sends it, below is my code:

```
router.post("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.userId) {
    res.status(204).send();
  } else {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    User.findById(req.session.userId, function (err, user) {
      if (err) return handleError(err); 

      const nameForDatabase = req.params.id + "Correct";  
      console.log(nameForDatabase);

      user.set({[nameForDatabase]: req.body.correct});

      user.save(function (err, updatedUser) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log(updatedUser);
      });
    });

    res.status(204).send();
  }
});
```

In desktop chrome this behaves as expected, with the post updating user data, and the page otherwise remaining the same. In iOS, a blank page is loaded.

Is there a way to stop a blank page from appearing on iPhones/iPads?

Many thanks in advance.

NB: https://simplenotesapp.herokuapp.com/fluids is a mock up of what I'm going for, it's important that the 204 doesn't load a new page, as you'll see that once the user has answered questions and submitted them at the bottom, the correct answers appear.

Comment: FYI, the way your code is written, it can call `res.status(204).send()` AND then call `handleError(err)`.  I don't know what `handleError(err)` does, but if you're expecting it to send an error status, that won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is a somewhat known issue in some browsers:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70226

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=368717

As a work-around, you could use a little bit of Javascript with Ajax in your web page to post your form instead of a default form post and then the current page won't be affected at all.

Just hook the submit button up to your Javascript and do e.preventDefault() to prevent the default form posting. Your JS can then post the form without affecting the current page.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I have since done and seems to work well. Many thanks for your time!

Comment: @Ask - If this helped you figure out your issue, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points on stack overflow for following the proper procedure.